# I'm trying to create a Calculator and I want to make my code such that When I click on the arithmetic Operators, I want them to run only once

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to javascript and am trying to create a Javascript calculator as a learning project

I want the specific arithmetic operators to appear only once until another value is specified in // the calculator
Explanations are greatly appreciated

````
```
    // All the button variables

    let operationButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-operation]');
    let numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-number]');
    
    let display = document.querySelector('[data-current-operand]');
    
    
    // function to display a certain number when the button is clicked
    
    const displayValue = function () {
      numberButtons.forEach(button => {
        button.addEventListener('click', () => {
          display.innerHTML += button.innerHTML;
        })
      })
````

How can i make my code as such that when the operation buttons are clicked they only appear once until another value is specified

````
      operationButtons.forEach(item => {
        item.addEventListener('click', () => {
    
          if (display.innerHTML != '') {
            display.innerHTML += item.innerHTML;
          }
        })
      });
    
    };

    ```
````

```js
let operationButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-operation]');
let numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-number]');

let display = document.querySelector('[data-current-operand]');


// function to display a certain number when the button is clicked

const displayValue = function () {
  numberButtons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
      display.innerHTML += button.innerHTML;
    })
  })

};
  operationButtons.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', () => {

      if (display.innerHTML != '') {
        display.innerHTML += item.innerHTML;
      }
    })
  });
```

```css
*,*::before,*::after{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
}

body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
}

.calculator-grid{
    display: grid;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 100px);
    grid-template-rows: minmax(120px, auto) repeat(5,100px);
}

.calculator-grid > button{
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 2rem;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    outline: none;
}

.calculator-grid > button:hover{
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)

}
    
.span-two{
    grid-column: span 2;
}

.output{
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 10px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    word-break: break-all;
}

.output .previous-operand{
     color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
     font-size: 1.5rem;
}
.output .current-operand{
     color: white;
     font-size: 2.5rem;
}
```

```html
  
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#">
  <title>Calculator</title>
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="calculator-grid">
    <div class="output">
      <div data-previous-operand class="previous-operand"></div>
      <div data-current-operand class="current-operand"></div>
    </div>
    <button data-all-clear class="span-two">AC</button>
    <button data-delete>DEL</button>
    <button data-operation class="button">÷</button>
    <button data-number>1</button>
    <button data-number>2</button>
    <button data-number>3</button>
    <button data-operation class="button">*</button>
    <button data-number>4</button>
    <button data-number>5</button>
    <button data-number>6</button>
    <button data-operation class="button">+</button>
    <button data-number>7</button>
    <button data-number>8</button>
    <button data-number>9</button>
    <button data-operation class="button">-</button>
    <button data-number>.</button>
    <button data-number>0</button>
    <button data-equals class="span-two">=</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a test using regular expression if the last digit of display is a number.

```
  operationButtons.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', () => {
      if (display.innerHTML != '') {
        if(/\d$/.test(display.innerHTML)){
          display.innerHTML += item.innerHTML;
        }
      }
    })
  });
```